# R does not load all rows of a text file to table

Tags: r, csv, read.table

I am trying to load a 580,000-line, 18-column tab-separated text file into R. It runs smoothly with no errors or warnings, but only ~290,000 lines are in the output table. The columns are a mix of numeric and text data, and many cells are blank (not set to NA). The file itself is only 80 MB, well within R's size limits.

```
b = read.table("myfile.txt", sep = '\t', fill = T, header = T)
dim(b)
[1] 293582     18
```

I need all 580,000 lines. Is there a way to prevent R from cutting them off?

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past - try adding the `quote="", comment.char=""` arguments - you may have embedded quotes or # characters causing rows to be dropped silently. If you are able to point to the file's location online (assuming it is not sensitive information), then we could determine the issue for sure).

Comment: change the command to be `b = read.table("myfile.txt", sep = '\t', blank.lines.skip = FALSE, header = TRUE)`

Comment: @Onyambu - i stand corrected - totally blank rows with only a `\t` separator seem to be dropped. Results differ depending on csv vs tsv though it appears `read.table(text="a\tb\n\t\n1\t2", blank.lines.skip=TRUE, header=TRUE);
read.csv(text="a,b\n,\n1,2", blank.lines.skip=TRUE, header=TRUE)`

Comment: it might be worth trying `data.table::fread()` or `readr::read_table()`; they're both probably faster, more robust, and may give more diagnostics than `read.table()`

Comment: @thelatemail - Thank you, adding `quote=""` worked.